# How to refer in CSS to all elements that have some attribute?

Tags: css, attributes

I know that `[my_attr='my_value']` refers to all elements which have attribute `my_attr` with value `my_value`.

Is that possible to refer to all elements which have `my_attr` attribute (no matter what the value is) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[my_attr]` [alone](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation):

> **[att]** Represents an element with the att attribute, whatever the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
element[attr]
```

That should do it.